# Column Chart groupPadding jQ chart

Tags: jqchart

I wanted column chart to look like this.
Where there are three columns representing gold,silver and bronze medals

[image]

Is there a way to adjust groupPadding betweenthe columns in column chart ?
If not ,is there any hack ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've answered you in our forum:

http://www.jqchart.com/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=166